# how show progressBar of Microsoft Ajax inside a button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I want to show progressBar of microsoft ajax that have an image inside one button, when user clicks that button. but i do not khow how to do that?I khow how show progressbar.my problem is showing it inside button!

```
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="up">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div class="PlaeseWaite">
        </div>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Comment: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/10/how-to-show-progressbar-during.html

Answer (score 0):

Your aspx code

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
.modalPopup
{
background-color: #696969;
filter: alpha(opacity=40);
opacity: 0.7;
xindex:-1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
//Raised before processing of an asynchronous postback starts and the postback request is sent to the server.
prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
// Raised after an asynchronous postback is finished and control has been returned to the browser.
prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
//Shows the modal popup - the update progress
var popup = $find('<%= modalPopup.ClientID %>');
if (popup != null) {
popup.show();
}
}

function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
//Hide the modal popup - the update progress
var popup = $find('<%= modalPopup.ClientID %>');
if (popup != null) {
popup.hide();
}
}
</script>
<div>
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress" runat="server">
<ProgressTemplate>
<asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="waiting.gif" AlternateText="Processing" runat="server" />
</ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="modalPopup" runat="server" TargetControlID="UpdateProgress"
PopupControlID="UpdateProgress" BackgroundCssClass="modalPopup" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlData" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="btnSubmit_Click"/>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and code behind

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```

Here is [Solution](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/10/how-to-show-progressbar-during.html)

Comment: it just show progress bar. it does not show progress bar inside button!